# Manage view from other class

Tags: objective-c, oop, viewcontroller, code-organization

I have several view controllers that need to make Parse services calls, which is therefore handled in a class for every "Parse" related work.

Now I have a case where the parse response will (if no errors comes up obviously) instantiate the MFMessageComposeViewController with certain parameters.

The text  body comes from parse, the recipients comes from the class.

My problem is : **I have copy/pasted code that I can't get rid off because I don't know what to do**

In my controller class, I do this :

```
- (void)showSMS:(NSString*)reciever {   //This is the phone number 

    if(![MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
        UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ALERT_ERROR_Title", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"ALERT_ERROR_NOSMS", nil) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [warningAlert show];
        return;
    }

    [[ParseService sharedInstance]sendSMSOfType:SMS_TYPE_INSIST toRecipient:reciever andBlock:^(NSError *error, NSString *body) {

        if (!error){

            MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
            messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;

            NSArray *recipents = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:reciever, nil];
            [messageController setRecipients:recipents];

            [messageController setBody:body];

            [self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }else{

            UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error getting sms" message:@"Couldn't get the text online" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [warningAlert show];
            return;   
        } 
    }];
}
```

and I have this exact same block of code in 3 different places, except for ONE difference, the `SMS_TYPE` parameter.

How should I tweak this so I don't have to create and assign the parameters in every controller, have one neat line that would look like this `[??? setUpMessageControllerWithParam:recipients:body];`

Pretty much the whole completion block here troubles me, but I can't really put it somewhere else because I'll have trouble presenting a view on `self` if `self` isn't a VC`,` same goes for `delegates` and `alerts`.

This is probably simple for most of you, I'm just OOP-retarded. Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: You seem to want to know about Object-Oriented Programming best practises (judging by the `oop` tag), however your opening sentence reveals issues with your understand of MVC: "I have several views that need to make Parse services calls".  Views don't make calls, that's a Controller's role.

Comment: That is very true, but I'll put that on the account of my poor phrasing ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do the this ... like creating a base view controller with this method passing the custom parameters and inheriting your other view controllers from it, or you can make a Category with this method and import this category and use wherever you need ...